# Python - Testing if part of XML child elements matches pattern - Do I use text search with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I what to inspect a bunch of blocks of XML to see if they match a predefined pattern.  In my example the two blocks I want to inspect are inside the `<case label="*****">`.  I am able to find the blocks without issue with the `findall` example below.  But I am not sure what is the best way to check the XML inside that block?  My goal is to see if the XML looks like the first block `E234` vs the second block `OBCF`.  For example the`OBCF` block has some extra text doing a `multiply.` 1)Is there a good single command that would extact all the child XML into text allowing me to text match on it?  If so I would most likely want to remove white space. 2)I know I can run `getchildren` to get the child XML but not sure the best way to iterate over this as on a comparison I could both fail on `the text being different or with` the nesting just being different.

```
for sm in xml_file.findall(
 "//ns:ruleDefinition[@name='ProcessAllFields']/ns:if/ns:then/ns:forEachField/ns:body/ns:switch/ns:case", namespaces={'ns': 'urn:x-namespacecom:API.services.ruleengine'}):

print(sm.attrib)  # prints the label tag

child = sm.getchildren()  # when inspecting I get mix of text and child elements
```

XML

```
          <case label="0xE234">
            <!--  TE_SOURCE_RT -->
            <if>
              <or>
                <equal op1="$temp.updateAlways" op2="true"/>
                <equal op1="#TH_SOURCE_RT" op2="0"/>
              </or>
              <then>
                <assign to="$TE_SOURCE_RT" from="$inField.data"/>
                <appendField field="$TE_EXCHANGE_SOURCE_RT"/>
              </then>
            </if>
          </case>
         <case label="0x04BCF">
            <!-- dec=1212,  CCC -->
            <if>
              <or>
                <equal op1="$temp.updateAlways" op2="true"/>
                <equal op1="#CCC" op2="0"/>
              </or>
              <then>
                <multiply op1="$inField.data" op2="$temp.pScale" store="$CCC" round="6"/>
              </then>
            </if>
          </case>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need beyond child level under a certain element, consider XPath's `descendant` axis to parse all all descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.). This requires `xpath()` in `lxml` and is not supported in `findall()`.

You can even use nested dict/list comprehension to build a dictionary of your parsed data where keys are the label attribute which assumes uniqueness across all case nodes.

```py
import lxml.etree as lx

xml_file = lx.parse(...)

nmsp = {'ns': 'urn:x-namespacecom:API.services.ruleengine'}

query = ( 
    "//ns:ruleDefinition[@name='ProcessAllFields']"
    "/ns:if/ns:then/ns:forEachField"
    "/ns:body/ns:switch/ns:case"
)

cases_dict = {
    case.attrib["label"]: [
        el.tag for el in case.xpath("descendant::*")
    ]
    for case in xml_file.xpath(query, namespaces=nmsp)
}
```

And since your XML is attribute-centric, you can parse all the descendant attributes easily for a dict of dicts where inner dict keys are element tags (assuming uniqueness under case nodes)

```py
cases_dict = {
    case.attrib["label"]: {
        f"{el.tag}_{i}": (
            el.attrib
            for i, el in 
            enumerate(case.xpath("descendant::*"), start=1)
        )
    }
    for case in xml_file.xpath(query, namespaces=nmsp)
}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, but like you said parsing the dict of dicts `assumes uniqueness`.   In my XML example under <or> there are two <equal> instances and only the second one appears.   But it seems like I can skips the last block of code and just edit ` el.tag for el in case.xpath("descendant::*")` to be `  (el.tag, el.attrib) for el in case.xpath("descendant::*")`.  See any downside of that?

Comment: See edit to dict of dicts using `enumerate` to suffix a counter to each descendant. First block with dict of lists should capture all descendants including repeat names.  Your suggestion would return a tuples of descendants' names and attributes, still capturing all instances. If that works for you, go for it.